# JUnit with hibernate: this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit

I'm doing a test by using JUnit.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:com/mt/sm/application-context.xml", "classpath:com/mt/sm/security-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class LocationPathServiceImplTest { /* Class code here */ }
```

The test method declaration is quite simple:

```
@Test
public void testRefresh() { /* Method body */}
```

I've created save an obj in the `setup()` and save to db.
While in `@Test` I run the `refresh()` from DAO (the refresh() method just calls  EntityManager .refresh()), but it causes me the error below

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Did anybody come across this before?
All suggestions would be appreciated.

At no point I commit the changes to the database nor I call .flush(). For my best understanding, they are within the current transaction.

Comment: Do you commit the transaction in the setup() method? You'll get that error if you're still in the same transaction (you'll be in an implicit transaction if you haven't explicitly declared one) as you were in when you created the object.

Comment: @CodeBrickie I've updated the code example and the description.

Comment: Can you also add your code from `setup()`? From what you have shown above you're not extending TestCase so you must use an annotation on your setup() method. See my answer below regarding `@before`. I would also like to see the code being executed in setup()

Answer (score 3):

Without more code I'd say, you need to `flush` your DAO so the instance gets persisted. `refresh` is only object level while `flush` does an actual transaction on database level (hence the `rollback = true` so it gets rolled back after the test)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the other answers saying you should `flush()` are correct as this will not commit anything to the database. See [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing). Flushing the Session simply gets the data that is currently in the session synchronized with what is in the database. So your exception makes sense if you have not called `myobject.save()` in your setUp() method.

I don't think you want to call `commit()` anywhere either becasue you want everything to rollback after your test completes. Use these annotations on your Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true) 
@Transactional
```

You can then add `@before` on your setUp() method although if your class extends TestCase this will be the same. Thor84no is correct in that the @before method will execute in the same transaction as your @Test method. If you actually wanted to seed the database with commited data you can use a method annotated with `@beforeTransaction` instead.

[EDIT]

Based on your updated question, it sounds like you have not called `persist()` or similar on the object you say you have created in setup() and it's considered to be dettached (i.e. not persisted to the database within your transaction).

Answer (score 0):

I would also flush / close / reopen session to force actual writing into database.

Comment: I'm trying not to commit anything into the database. So far it's working great for other test cases, this is the first time I come across the EntityManager .refresh() method, so maybe that's the problem.